# How do I add a .jar file into an IntelliJ IDEA Java project?

Tags: java, sql-server, intellij-idea

I have a java project loaded into IntelliJ IDEA.  The code requires JDBC and so I downloaded and unzipped the sqljdbc_6.4.0.0_enu file into the recommended directory, "C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.4 for SQL Server".  This creates the  jar files:

- mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre7.jar
- mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar
- mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre9.jar

in the directory, "C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.4 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_6.4\enu".  And so, now, how do I make use of all this in my project in IntelliJ IDEA?  And if I later put all my java code into Git Hub, how can I ensure that another user will have code that will compile and link?  Will I have to include the .jar file in Git Hub somehow?

Comment: I recommend you look into build tools such as Maven or Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

you should not do this. For your case, you can choose one of them:

1. create lib foder into project folder - put .jar files in the folder- setup module with library point to the folder - commit metadata folder of IDEA such as .idea, {projectName}.iml (not recommend)
2. The best solution is using maven or Gradle, you are able to put the dependencies which are neccessary into pom.xml file. (Recommend)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project) for adding external jar files in IntelliJ IDEA.

As for GitHub, you can put your jar files there by removing *.jar from .gitignore configuration file. However this is not a recommended practice to have JAR files in repository as they've considerable size. You can consider using some build tool(maven or gradle) to add external dependencies.